# NTFS partition access

Tags: mount

A USB flashdrive was burned with a bootable lubuntu install partition and an NTFS partition (gParted).   Attempts to access the NTFS partition fail.

It is showing the error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media/lubuntu/NTFS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999" "/dev/sdb2" "/media/lubuntu/NTFS"' exited with non-zero exit status 21: ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Device or resource busy
```

What prevents NTFS mounting?  Needs to be done to gain access to the NTFS partition?

I am unable to access the USB device from lubuntu and Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It may be that your device is busy try logging into each user on your system and cd to the home directory, a dism wont mount if you are inside the home drectory

Answer (score 2):

If you are mounting an NTFS partition it is possible that this partition, from Windows was as hibernate. Restart Windows and shut down it completely. 
Then, try again

Comment: Interesting!  The USB device has never been in a Windows device.

Answer (score 1):

According to `mount(2)` man page, there are three possible causes for EBUSY (= `Device or resource busy`) error from a `mount()` system call:

- `/dev/sdb2` might be already mounted.
- On remount operations, a filesystem cannot be remounted read-only if it still has files open for writing. (This doesn't seem applicable in your case.)
- Or the specified filesystem cannot be mounted on target mountpoint because the **mountpoint** is busy: it might be the current working directory of some process (e.g. a shell session perhaps?), or be the mount point of some other device already.

The exit status 21 from `ntfs-3g-mount` (also known as `mount.ntfs-3g`) seems to be "unclassified FUSE error", at least according to man pages on my Debian 9 system.

If I understand your background information correctly, this is a (possibly minimal) Lubuntu installation on the same USB flash drive. Are you sure the installation includes all the components of FUSE? Is the `fuse` kernel module getting loaded successfully (check with `lsmod`)?

Comment: Thanks for the diagnostic question:  `lsmod | grep -i fuse`  does not return anything (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: If the `fuse` kernel module is missing, that might explain why NTFS-3g is not working. Please run `grep FUSE /boot/config-$(uname -r)`. If it says `CONFIG_FUSE_FS=y`, then the functionality is built into the main kernel; if it says `CONFIG_FUSE_FS=m`, then the problem could be that the `fuse.ko` kernel module is missing from your Lubuntu installation. And if it says `# CONFIG_FUSE_FS is not set`, then you have a stripped-down kernel with no FUSE and so unable to use NTFS-3G.